# Handling KeyboardInterrupt in context manager __enter__ method

Tags: python, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I'm writing code that I want to be usable in interactive shell, like IPython, that means that the code needs to be able to handle a completely asynchronous, and unexpected, exception like `KeyboardInterrupt` and still be functional after it. I guess I should use context managers to handle locking and unlocking.

Problem is, what if the exception is raised *during* the execution of `__enter__` or `__exit__` method and I need to acquire multiple locks in the `__enter__` method and release multiple ones in `__exit__`?

My understanding is that calls to C code are atomic and all the bytecode instructions are atomic. So the call to `thread.Lock.acquire()` won't be interrupted, as will the assignment of the result of that call to a variable. But, we don't have a guarantee that an exception won't be raised *between* the return from `acquire()` and assignment of the return value to a variable (as that's handled by two different operations on bytecode level).

In other words, code like this:

```py
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
while True:
    locked = False
    try:
        locked = lock.acquire()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if locked:
            lock.release()
            locked = False
        raise
    finally:
        if locked:
            lock.release()
```

**won't** always release the `lock` on Ctrl+C.

similarly, the following script will sometimes fail the last `assert` check:

```py
import sys
import threading

class ComplexLock():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock_a = threading.Lock()
        self.lock_b = threading.Lock()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.lock_a.acquire()
        self.lock_b.acquire()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.lock_b.release()
        self.lock_a.release()

    def state_consistent(self):
        return not self.lock_a.locked() and not self.lock_b.locked()


a = ComplexLock()
assert a.state_consistent()

try:
    while True:
        with a:
            pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
finally:
    assert a.state_consistent()
```

(side note: I can't use `lock.locked()` in place of `locked` as I don't know if it's the current thread that is holding the lock; `lock` is global and shared, `locked` is thread-local)

So, **the question** is how to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` in a way that doesn't corrupt global objects?

A practical example use case:
Consider that you want to calculate `e**x`, but for that sake of argument, the computation time is long and depends on value of `x`.
As a library vendor, I provide the `e` as an export so the user can do

```py
from example_library import e
e**12
```

Now, because the calculation take a lot of time, I want to cache internally some precomputed variables (not results, I'm aware of [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) and it won't work for my real use case). So even though `e` doesn't change externally, it does change internally. But *that's an implementation detail unknown to the user*.
So when a user does a ^C because `e**10000` takes too long, it is reasonable for the user to expect that doing a `e**12` after that ^C will work just fine.

But it won't work fine if the lock used to synchronise the cache of precomputed variables was locked but not freed during previous calculation.

Comment: Unless you deliberately suppress the Exception (via ``signal``), there is no way to exhaustively handle it; since it is asynchronous, it might be raised again while handling it, and this might in theory happen up to arbitrary recursion. Can you clarify what you consider proper handling of ``KeyboardInterrupt``? Since the point of ``KeyboardInterrupt`` is to signal shutdown, it seems the proper response is termination of the application; this will naturally remove the need to release in-process locks.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi like I said, it's for use case of IPython, when you have global objects with locks, you want the user to be able to abort long calculation with Ctrl+C and still have a consistent environment. So, no, `KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't mean process termination.

Comment: Now that we have cleared up that termination is not what you expect to happen, can you clarify what you expect to actually happen? What is the expected behavior? So far I see only what you don’t expect to happen. What do you expect to happen if the lock is held by a child thread, which is naturally protected from KeyboardInterrupt? Does this have to work just for ipython or regular programs as well?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the situation is that a user can start a long running calculation, with a small critical section that uses global objects. After Ctrl+C by the user I don't want the global objects inoperable because their lock state is inconsistent (locked despite no code running). It should work both for interactive mode of the python interpreter and IPython.

Comment: Is the computation actually costly, i.e. do you want ^C to just return the prompt or should it also kill the calculation?

Comment: actually, I think it needs to work in a regular python too: I can imagine situation where the application allows the user to do a Ctrl+C to skip some calculations, discard those results and continue with more, unrelated calculations.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the calculation is costly, I want to abort it at arbitrary place

Comment: Does that mean you must also be able to abort it if it is not running in the main thread? The use of locking to protect the shared state across threads seems to imply this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the locking is there because I don't know if the code will be used in multithreaded application or not. Generally the ^C would happen only in single-threaded code, but I can't assume that. If a user starts a thread that does a call to my library that takes a long time, they won't be able to abort it immediately, but that's true for all python code, so it's not surprising. Not being able to do calculation with objects that appear immutable (but because implementation detail internally aren't) after a ^C is surprising and arguably a bug.

Comment: Okay, that's probably something to work with (it would still be nice to have the requirements in the actual questions). Please be aware though that since threading seems not part of your intended use-case, the common way would be to document your computation as not threadsafe. This means that users opt-in to thread protection *suitable for their use-case*, instead of you having to guess what these use-cases are and how to protect them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225897/discussion-between-hubert-kario-and-mistermiyagi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it looks like it's not possible in general sense, it's a bug in python: https://bugs.python.org/issue29988
and also it's a known deficiency, see [PEP 419](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0419/) (unfortunately [deferred](https://bugs.python.org/issue14730)). And the more specific for this case: https://bugs.python.org/issue31388

the short of it is that even if the `__enter__` and `__exit__` are C functions, it's not guaranteed that the `__exit__` will get called even if the `__enter__` executed successfully, we can just patch it up on python level to make it less likely, not impossible

by implementing our own signal handler and deferring the signal delivery, we can make it fairly robust, but only if the critical section is expected to be short, so the deferral won't impact the user

to continue example from the question, something like this seems to work as expected, even if we introduce threads into the mix:

```py
import sys
import signal
import threading

class ComplexLock():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock_a = threading.Lock()
        self.lock_b = threading.Lock()

    def __enter__(self):
        if threading.current_thread().__class__.__name__ == '_MainThread':
            # only MainThread can handle signals
            self.signal_received = False
            self.old_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self._handler)

        self.lock_a.acquire()
        self.lock_b.acquire()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.lock_b.release()
        self.lock_a.release()

        if threading.current_thread().__class__.__name__ == '_MainThread':
            signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.old_handler)
            if self.signal_received:
                self.old_handler(*self.signal_received)

    def _handler(self, sig, frame):
        self.signal_received = (sig, frame)

    def state_consistent(self):
        return not self.lock_a.locked() and not self.lock_b.locked()

lock = ComplexLock()
assert lock.state_consistent()
import time
def countdown(x):
    while x[0]:
        with x[1]:
            pass

param = [True, lock]

t = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=(param, ))
t.start()

try:
    while True:
        with lock:
            pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    param[0] = False
    t.join()
    sys.exit(0)
finally:
    assert lock.state_consistent()
```

(there are obviously races when multiple signals get delivered, and some can get dropped, but that's less of a problem than broken environment after Ctrl+C)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a good way to handle this with `KeyboardInterrupt`, but you could handle it with signals.

In Python, `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised by the default handler for `SIGNINT` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)). You can define your own signal handler to do something else, and handle it when you want.

```py
import os
import signal
import threading

interrupted = False


def signal_handler(signal_number, frame):
    global interrupted
    interrupted = True


original_signal_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

lock = threading.Lock()
while not interrupted:
    locked = False
    try:
        locked = lock.acquire()
        # Do something while holding the lock
    finally:
        if locked:
            lock.release()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_signal_handler)
if os.name == "nt":
    # Windows needs a special case because kill() doesn't send SIGINT.
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
else:
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```

I haven't tested the Windows version, but it should work.

You should take care to make sure your code exits quickly after `interrupted` is set.

Comment: problem is that I'm doing it in a library not in an application, so I can't assume that I can use the SIGINT handler

Comment: You're assuming that `KeyboardInterrupt` will be raised, so that means you're assuming the application using your library won't set its own signal handler. In that case, could you set your own handler, do your thing, and then restore the default handler an send the signal again?

Comment: How do I do it in a way that the code I'm wrapping in the context manager still can get interrupted with the Ctrl+C?

Comment: You still have a custom handler between `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()`, so "# Do something while holding the lock` won't get interrupted

Comment: You mean you're calling back to user code while holding the lock?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225892/discussion-between-nadav-zingerman-and-hubert-kario).